# How to merge multiple rows into single cell in csv separated by comma using Python

Tags: python, csv, newline

here is my problem:

in my csv file, I only have one column and multiple rows containing telephone numbers.

```
    a 
1  222
2  333
3  444
4  555
```

what I want is merge them into one string and separate by comma, eg:

```
   a
1  222,333,444,555
```

The code I am using right now is:

```
import csv

b = open('test.csv', 'wb')
a = csv.writer(b)

s = ''
with open ("book2.csv", "rb") as annotate:
    for col in annotate:

        ann = col.lower().split(",")
        s += ann[0] + ','
s = s[:-1] # Remove last comma

a.writerow([s])
b.close()
```

what I get from this is

```
   a
1   222,
    333,
    444,
    555
```

All the numbers are in one cell now (good) but they are not on one line (there is /r/n after each telephone number so I think that's why they are not on one line). Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import csv

b = open('test.csv', 'wb')
a = csv.writer(b)

s = ''
with open ("book2.csv", "rb") as annotate:
    for col in annotate:

        ann = col.lower().strip('\n').split(",")
        s += ann[0] + ','
s = s[:-1] # Remove last comma

a.writerow([s])
b.close()
```

Comment: Thank you! That's what I wanted. So I just need to strip the \n for every item.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `csv` module, but ignoring `csv.reader`.  It handles all the parsing for you:

```
#!python2
import csv
with open('book2.csv','rb') as inf, open('test.csv','wb') as outf:
    r = csv.reader(inf)
    w = csv.writer(outf)
    L = [row for row in r] # Read all lines as list of lists.
    L = zip(*L)            # transpose all the lines.
    w.writerows(L)         # Write them all back out.
```

Input:

```
222
333
444
555
```

Output in the .csv file:

```
222,333,444,555
```

**EDIT:** I see now that you want the data in Excel to be in a single cell.  The above will put it in a row of four cells:

[image]

The following will write a single cell:

```
#!python2
import csv
with open('book2.csv') as inf, open('test.csv','wb') as outf:
    w = csv.writer(outf)
    data = inf.read().splitlines()
    w.writerow([','.join(data)])
```

Output in the .csv file:

```
"222,333,444,555"
```

Output in Excel:

[image]

Comment: Hi I am using Python 2, but I get this instead:
two rows. First row only has the first telephone number ie 222
second row has the other 3 numbers 333  444 555 but they are not in one cell and not I couldn't see the commas

Comment: @Kyle, you copied the code exactly?  With the exact input data shown?

Comment: Look at the file in notepad not Excel. But I think I understand now that what you really want is `"222,333,444,555"` so it shows up in a single cell in Excel. Note the quotes.

Comment: I tried this with 70k rows of ingredients list and for some reason, they come out different. It's odd. I find 61942 matches of the search "Aqua" in one and 55143 of "Aqua" in the test.csv file...